# Postgres json select

Tags: postgresql

Let's say that I have an incoming JSON message to my app:

```
      {
        line_nbr : 1,
        value: 10
       },   

           {
        line_nbr : 2,
        value: 30
       },   

   ]
```

Is it possible to perform the following selection in postgres :

```
SELECT  JsonObject.value, qty   from table_x  where id in  JsonObjects.line_nbr
```

In other words join on the incoming JSON object

Answer (score 1):

```
with your_js as (
 select (value->>'line_nbr')::int as line_nbr
 from jsonb_array_elements('JsonObjects'::jsonb) as je
)
select line_nbr, qty
from table_x
 join your_js on line_nbr = table_x.id
```

check [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) for detail